# How to use jsonb column in index update function for full text search?

Tags: postgresql

I have an `articles` table with these (relevant) fields

```sql
CREATE TABLE
  IF NOT EXISTS articles (
    ...
    ...
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    content JSONB NOT NULL,
    search_index TSVECTOR NOT NULL,
    ...
    ...
  );
```

with an index on `search_index`

```sql
CREATE INDEX articles_search_index ON articles USING gin(search_index);
```

And I want to be able to search both `title` and `content` without any particular priority.

I want to *treat* entire `content` data as a blob of text without actually changing its structure.

What I'd hope would work:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER articles_search_index_update BEFORE INSERT
OR
UPDATE
  ON articles FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION 
     tsvector_update_trigger
        (search_index,
         'pg_catalog.english', 
          title, 
          content
        );
```

Error - `column \"content\" is not of a character type` which is understandable since `tsvector_update_trigger` expects text columns.

Is it possible to have `jsonb` content in that function?

Comment: What about using a generated column instead of the trigger based solution?

Comment: I haven't thought about it, but if it works, I'd be happy to refactor away the trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generated column with `jsonb_to_tsvector()`. As you also want to index the title, you will need to concatenate the `content` column with a JSON value containing the title.

Something along the lines:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles 
(
  ...
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  content JSONB NOT NULL,
  search_index TSVECTOR generated always as 
     (jsonb_to_tsvector('english', content||jsonb_object(array['title', title]), '"all"')) stored
);
```

Note that you can not use `jsonb_build_object()` as that is unfortunately not marked as "immutable", but `jsonb_object()` is.

If the JSON stored in the `content` column can contain a top-level key `title`, you will need to use a different key, maybe `jsonb_object(array['__title', title])`.

One advantage I can see (apart from not having to manage the trigger) is, that this only indexes the actual JSON *values* not the keys, so I would expect this to result in more accurate search results.

Comment: Works perfectly! About JSON values tho, I see `'"all"'` is also indexing object keys. Perhaps I need to use array of filters like `'["string", "numeric", "boolean"]'`.

Comment: @iovo: you can tweak it as you want. But the "all" seemed to match what you expected by the trigger solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the entire json to a string by using `content::text` instead of `content` in the update trigger, but then all the brackets, keys and commas of the json would also get thrown in which could be problematic. If content always contains the same simple properties it will be much cleaner to manually extract the (relevant) properties, cast them to text where necessary and concatenating them together instead.